# Leaflet and MongoDB radius

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geospatial, leaflet

I want to use leaflet marker (for latLng) and a slider (for radius) for my search form.
The mongodb part will be like

```
location: {
  $geoWithin: {
    $centerSphere: [[lon, lat], radius]
  }
}
```

But the radius seems never to be the right one.
What number must I divide/multiply to get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the same unit for all (the map and the search).
I prefer using meter in this case.

Leaflet already used the meter unit.
So you only need to make your query using meter.
According to [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/), you should use GeoJSON.
And make sure the index is "2dsphere".